# Clipping mask effect for images using KineticJS

Tags: html, kineticjs

I want the Clipping mask effect for images in HTML5. Please find my 
If I use

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v3.8.3.js

instead of

http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.4.1.min.js

it works fine with creating stage object as- 
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage("container", 800, 800);

how to implement this feature with v4.4.1.min.js?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**There are several ways to do clipping in KineticJS**

You can use a fill pattern inside one of the predefined shapes like this:

```
        var clipWithFill = new Kinetic.Circle({
          …
          fillPatternImage: img,
          fillPatternOffset: [-160, 90],
          …
        });
```

And you can create a custom shape that uses html canvas’s clip();

```
        var clipWithCustomShape = new Kinetic.Shape({
          drawFunc: function(canvas) {
            var context = canvas.getContext();
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();

            // draw our clipping shape
            Context.rect(100,100,100,150);
            // set it as the context's clipping region
            context.clip();
            // draw the image which will be clipped
            context.drawImage(img,50,75);
            // restore the context to it’s unclipped state
            context.restore();
          },
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 5
        });
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/MWSx9/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
      canvas{border:1px solid red;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer">

        function drawClips(img) {

            var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                container: 'container',
                width: 400,
                height: 300
            });
            var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

            var clipWithFill = new Kinetic.Circle({
                x: 100,
                y: 100,
                radius: 75,
                fillPatternImage: img,
                fillPatternOffset: [30, 90],
                fillPatternRepeat: "no-repeat",
                stroke: 'black',
                strokeWidth: 5,
                draggable: true
            });
            layer.add(clipWithFill);


            var clipWithCustomShape = new Kinetic.Shape({
                drawFunc: function (canvas) {
                    var context = canvas.getContext();
                    context.save();
                    context.beginPath();

                    // draw our custom clipping shape
                    drawOurCustomShape(context)
                    // set it as the context's clipping region
                    context.clip();
                    // draw the image which will be clipped
                    context.drawImage(img, 200, 75);
                    //
                    context.restore();
                    // re-draw our custom shape
                    // just to outline our clipped region
                    drawOurCustomShape(context);
                    canvas.fillStroke(this);
                },
                stroke: 'black',
                strokeWidth: 5,
                draggable: true
            });
            layer.add(clipWithCustomShape);


            function drawOurCustomShape(context) {
                context.moveTo(200, 150);
                context.bezierCurveTo(250, 170, 300, 20, 390, 100);
                context.lineTo(350, 220);
                context.lineTo(250, 220);
                context.closePath();
            }

            stage.add(layer);
        }


        function houseToPNG() {
            var tempCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
            tempCanvas.width = 140;
            tempCanvas.height = 140;
            drawHouse(tempCtx);
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                tempCanvas = null;
                drawClips(img);
            }
            img.src = tempCanvas.toDataURL();
        }

        function drawHouse(ctx) {
            ctx.save();
            // roof
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "gray";
            ctx.lineWidth = 4;
            ctx.moveTo(5, 40);
            ctx.lineTo(135, 40);
            ctx.lineTo(70, 4);
            ctx.closePath()
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            // frame
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "gray";
            ctx.lineWidth = 4;
            ctx.rect(20, 40, 100, 100);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            // windows
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "lightgray";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
            ctx.lineWidth = 3;
            ctx.rect(40, 55, 20, 25);
            ctx.rect(80, 55, 20, 25);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = "tan"
            ctx.moveTo(42, 68);
            ctx.lineTo(58, 68);
            ctx.moveTo(82, 68);
            ctx.lineTo(98, 68);
            ctx.moveTo(50, 57);
            ctx.lineTo(50, 78);
            ctx.moveTo(90, 57);
            ctx.lineTo(90, 78);
            ctx.stroke();
            // door
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
            ctx.lineWidth = 3;
            ctx.rect(60, 95, 20, 40);
            ctx.rect(73, 115, 1, 1);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            //
            ctx.restore();
        }

        houseToPNG();

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ markE Thanks. That is really helpful. One more question, can I make image draggable. So that I can make only required portion of the image visible.

Comment: @vDeepak: Sure.  For the predefined circle, just add draggable:true.  For the custom shape, add draggable:true **and** change to canvas.fillStroke(this).

Comment: no. Not able to make image draggable. Cant understand. Making draggable true, will make image draggable or circle?

Comment: See my expanded answer which now includes making the clipped images draggable.

Comment: Thanks for discussion. Just seen the result but that is not what I expect. I want only image draggable not container(here, circle). Is it possible to make only image draggable and not circle.

Comment: I need help understanding your question.  Do you want to drag a circle over an image and the only part of the image that is visible is the part that the circle is over?  If yes, then you can use your circle's dragmove event to change the fillPatternOffset to "view" a different part of the image like this: clipWithFill.on('dragmove', function() { clipWithFill.setFillPatternOffset([newImageX,newImageY]); });

Comment: Continued from previous comment: And if you want the circle not to move but the image inside the circle to move, you can use your circle's mousemove event to change the fillPatternOffset to "view" a different part of the image like this: clipWithFill.on('mousemove', function() { clipWithFill.setFillPatternOffset([newImageX,newImageY]); });

Comment: I am getting this error in your fiddle = TypeError: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.fill '[object CanvasRenderingContext2D]' is not a valid value for enumeration CanvasWindingRule.

Answer (score 0):

You can set clipping masks with the setClipFunc method:

http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Container.html (see clip)

you can use this for any container, including the stage, layers, or groups.  Everything inside the clipping mask will be visible, and everything outside of the clipping mask will be invisible